# how to auto delete content using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image included with an img tag in my html. It is inside of a div with the class "image". Inside that div is another div with the class of "caption". That "caption" div contains a paragraph.

How can I delete the paragraph in the "caption" div and delete the "caption" div itself using javascript or jQuery?

```js
/* Script to delete the paragraph and caption div. */

$(".image img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        getClass = $this.attr('img')
    splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
    if (splitClass[1] <= 20) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");

    } else if (splitClass[1] >= 40) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

    } else {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image">
 <img id="img-1" src="http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg" />
 <div class="caption">
  <p>DELETE THIS TEXT!</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="image">
 <img id="img-2" src="http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg" />
 <div class="caption">
  <p>DELETE THIS TEXT!</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also, how can I use jQuery offline? Do I have to download it? How do I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: document.querySelector('.caption').remove()

Comment: https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: @Federico in where i put it?

Comment: no, i mean can you write the code 'document.querySelector('caption').remove() in my jQuery code?

Comment: I answered below `this.nextElementSibling.remove();` removes both the .caption and p tags.

Comment: Please use consistent and proper indentations in your code.

Comment: i'm sorry but can you look here the problem https://jsfiddle.net/wsv389td/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".image img").each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        getClass = $this.attr('img');
    this.nextElementSibling.remove();
    splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
    if (splitClass[1] <= 20) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");

    } else if (splitClass[1] >= 40) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

    } else {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
    }
});
```

Comment: use `this.nextElementSibling.remove();`  instead

Answer (score 2):

This would delete all elements that are `p` inside elements with class `.caption`.

```
$(".caption p").remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wsv389td/

JQuery can be used offline by getting the files, or min files, from here: https://jquery.com/download/

If you stored the file in the same directory as the HTML file using it you would put

`<script src="<name-of-jquery>.js"></script>`

If it was in a JS folder that is in the same directory as your HTML (very common) you would put:

`<script src="js/<name-of-jquery>.js"></script>`

Either one of these would go inside the head of you HTML

Comment: "i want delete the (.caption) and (p) using JavaScript or jQuery". Is that not what you asked for? Please be more concise in your question if that is not what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yep, +1 any answers that helped you so other realize which are solutions and which are not.

Comment: it says i must get "15 repuptation" i'm new in here